# AWS Boto3 Remember Me Implementation Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a web app that I am working on which uses AWS Cognito for authentication. I'm using the Boto3 SDK.

I am trying to implement a "Remember Me" checkbox. I'm a bit confused as to how the `DeviceSecretVerifierConfig` parameter in the `confirm_device` is suppose to be created.

This is what I currently have:

```
esp = client.admin_initiate_auth(
    UserPoolId=COG_USER_POOL,
    ClientId=COG_USER_POOL_APP,
    AuthFlow='ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={
        'USERNAME': username,
        'PASSWORD': password,
    },
    ClientMetadata={
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
    })

resp = client.confirm_device(
    AccessToken=resp['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken'],
    DeviceKey=resp['AuthenticationResult']['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceKey'],
    DeviceSecretVerifierConfig={
       **How do I populate this?**
    }
)

if remember: 
    remember_status = 'remembered'
else:
    remember_status = 'not_remembered'

resp = client.admin_update_device_status(
    UserPoolId=COG_USER_POOL,
    Username=username,
    DeviceKey=resp['AuthenticationResult']['NewDeviceMetadata']['DeviceKey'],
    DeviceRememberedStatus=remember_status
)
```

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled which is why you're trying to track the device or do you really just want to have a typical "Remember Me" which doesn't prompt the user for login?

Comment: I'm only looking to have the typical "Remember Me" which doesn't prompt the user, there is no 2FA involved. @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: If there's no MFA, **don't do this at all** - tracking devices is only for 2FA enabled solutions! Just store the value, and if they select "Remember Me" use the refresh token to refresh their access token when it expires.

Comment: So store the "remember_me" flag in local storage and then when the access token expires and the flag is set refresh? Will I run into any issues where a user who has not selected remember me is browsing the website logged in when suddenly their session is terminated due to their access token expiring and not having it refreshed?

Comment: Yes correct - in that case, if they are currently logged in then either let it log out and prompt them to log back in or refresh their token. The choice is up to you based on your business logic.